# How to invoke function that return an Observable within a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have the following function that traverse the tree-like object and it working fine so far.

```
const traverse = async (menuInputs: MenuInput[], parent: Menu = null) => {
  for (const input of menuInputs) {
    const entity = toEntity(input, parent);
    const parentMenu = await this.menuService.create(entity).toPromise();
    if (isEmpty(input.children)) {
      continue;
    }
    await traverse(input.children, parentMenu);
  }
};
```

My question is how can i invoke method `this.menuService.create(entity)` that is actually return an `Observable<Menu>` without convert it to `Promise`, are there any `RxJS` way of doing this ?

Comment: what does `this.menuService.create(entity)` return ?

Comment: @PawanSharma: OP already told us; check out the last sentence in his question.

Answer (score 1):

I've got something like this for recursive observable calls using the `HttpService`. You can probably work with something similar.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CharacterReaderApiService implements CharacterReader {
  private characters: SwapiCharacter[] = [];
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  async getCharacters(): Promise<Character[]> {
    console.log('Querying the API for character data...');
    return this.callUrl('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return data.map(this.mapPerson);
        }),
        tap(async (data) =>
          promises.writeFile(join(process.cwd(), characterFile), JSON.stringify(data)),
        ),
      )
      .toPromise();
  }

  private callUrl(url: string): Observable<SwapiCharacter[]> {
    return this.http.get<SwapiResponse>(url).pipe(
      map((resp) => resp.data),
      mergeMap((data) => {
        this.characters.push(...data.results);
        return iif(() => data.next !== null, this.callUrl(data.next), of(this.characters));
      }),
    );
  }

  private mapPerson(data: SwapiCharacter): Character {
    return {
      name: data.name,
      hairColor: data.hair_color,
      eyeColor: data.eye_color,
      gender: data.gender,
      height: data.height,
    };
  }
}
```

The important thing is keeping a running array of the values so that they can be referenced later on.

By using `mergeMap` with `iif` we're able to recursively call observables and work with the result as necessary. If you don't like the idea of a class variable for it, you could make the running array a part of the `callUrl` (or similar) method's parameters and pass it on as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strive to change `toEntity()` and `menuService.create()` to receive the list of children rather than the parent so I could use `forkJoin`:

```
const buildMenu = (input: MenuInput) => 
  forkJoin(
    input.children.map(childInput => buildMenu(childInput, menu))
  ).pipe(
    flatMap(childMenus => this.menuService.create(toEntity(input, childMenus)))
  );
```